# Chrome suggest password in login page

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a web app that when I open it in chrome on my cellphone, it suggests generating password in the login page, like this.

[image]

The question is, how can I add some semantics to my html field that chrome just suggests strong password generation in **registration** page and not in *login* page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the `autocomplete` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).

Set it to `current-password` or `new-password` as applicable.

Comment: Thanks, I tested, it shows a new button for suggesting the new password in `registration` page.